# How to fix 'Error Occured: 'FirefoxWebElement' object is not subscriptable'

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have tried to extract web elements 
and it give frequently this error:

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver=webdriver.Firefox()
singer_name='Avenged sevenfold'.replace(' ','+')
url=r'https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query='+singer_name
driver.get(url)
obj_lists=driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('a')
driver.minimize_window()

for index,songs in enumerate(obj_lists):
    try:
        print(songs[index].text)
    except Exception as error:
        print(error)


driver.close()
```

annoying Output

> Error Occured 'FirefoxWebElement' object is not subscriptable

Comment: sorry sir, I am New in Programming World and Don't know how to write to  ask for help ....now i Have posted the whole code.....please help me

Answer (score 0):

`obj_lists` represents the list of all `a` tags, as `FirefoxWebElement` objects. So when you try to loop on this list, you don't have to add an index to each item: `songs` is already an instance of `FirefoxWebElement` with all the properties you're looking for, like `text`, and you can access it directly.

You can even get rid of the `enumerate` function :

```
for songs in obj_lists:
    try:
        print(songs.text)
    except Exception as error:
        print(error)
```